# Converting decimal 100 to 31 30 30 in Batch

Tags: batch-file, decimal, ascii

I'm trying to convert a number from a text file - lets say number.txt - from decimal 100 to ASCII 31 30 30.

Is there something I can do in batch?

I tried several things I've found on SO already - but never had the right output.

Later after I have converted that - I need to add one number up after some execution. So lets say after 109 / 31 30 39 - it should be 110 31 31 30 and not 31 30 3a for example.

Can you give me a hint?

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (nummer.txt) do (
    set line=%%a
    set a=!line:~0,1!
    set line=%%a
    set b=!line:~1,1!
    set line=%%a
    set c=!line:~2,1!
    set /a mitte=3!a!3!b!3!c!
    echo 0F0900000A00143030303030303030303030303030303030!mitte!00>com3
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm confused. You say textfile, so why is your number '1' '0' '0' not 0x31 0x30 0x30?

Comment: Why are you splitting each character into individual ones, then converting each separately? Please try to explain the overall task, not just this small part of it, in order that we can offer the most efficient solution.

Comment: Its for encoding something - theres only one variable inside that.
So after succeeding with one - i need to count the number +1.

I'm doing it like that now:

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (nummer.txt) do (
  set line=%%a
  set a=!line:~0,1!

  set line=%%a
  set b=!line:~1,1!

  set line=%%a
  set c=!line:~2,1!
set /a mitte=3!a!3!b!3!c!

echo 0F0900000A00143030303030303030303030303030303030!mitte!00>com3

In nummer.txt I have a decimal number - 401 for example - but the encoding has to be in ASCII. So 34 40 41 :)

Comment: Your code in the comment above is practically unreadable, but it is ceratinly incomplete. I have edited your question to include my best guess of it, but it requires fixing. Please edit your question to fix that code yourself, or at least close the open loop, and add the rest of the information from your commernt above, to your question deleting the comment, which will no longer be required.

Comment: Sorry and thanks Compo - I'm rather new to SO so I didnt knew how to format rightly. I closed the loop - and doing like this - it will make the right output. Text file includes only one number (that I have to count up after every successfull run) - thats why I do it like this. This will make out of my 401 in the text - a 34 30 31 - I put it to together into the echo >com3 sting and it works as it is supposed to work :)

Comment: @JonasLenz, I have rolled back your previous edit. Please do not add 'solutions' directly to your question, we have an answer area designed, just for that. BTW, I have myself included an answer for you to read, learn from, and hopefully use, as an alternative to the version posted to your question. Please also delete the [no longer required comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61458473/converting-decimal-100-to-31-30-30-in-batch#comment108722740_61458473), I asked you to remove earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see if the following `Rem`arked [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) example helps you out.

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Rem Undefine any existing variable named inputNum.
Set "inputNum="
Rem Read input number from first line of input file.
Set /P "inputNum="<"nummer.txt"
Rem Exit script if inputNum was not defined.
If Not Defined inputNum GoTo :EOF
Rem Define a number of additional iterations [number results required - 1].
Set "#=9"
Rem Define an increment size.
Set "i=5"

Rem Define a variable for total increase, [# x i].
Set /A $=#*i
Rem Undefine an existing variable named arg.
Set "arg="
Rem Begin looping for stated iterations.
For /L %%G In (0,%i%,%$%)Do (
    Set /A arg=inputNum+%%G
    Rem Call subfunction passing the input number as an argument.
    Call :Sub "!arg!"
    Rem If successful,
    If Defined mitte (
        Rem Output resultant number sequence.
        Echo !mitte!
    ) Else (
        Rem Exit if no result sequence.
        GoTo EndIt
    )
)

:EndIt
Rem Allow time to read output before ending.
Pause
EndLocal
GoTo :EOF

:Sub
Rem Undefine any existing variable named mitte.
Set "mitte="
Rem Split each character of passed argument.
For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ('"Cmd /U/C Echo(%~1|Find /V """')Do (
    Rem prefix each digit of inputNum with 3.
    If Not Defined mitte (Set "mitte=3%%G")Else Set "mitte=!mitte!3%%G")
Rem return to next command line after previous Call
Exit /B
```

For testing, you should only need to ensure that your input file path is correct, *(line `6`)*. I have additionally include a facility to output a specific number of additional iterations, *(line `10`)*, with a fixed increment, *(line `12`)*. Please adjust those as necessary.

What that does if `nummer.txt` contains only `401`, with `9` additional iterations incrementing by `5` should output:

```bat
343031
343036
343131
343136
343231
343236
343331
343336
343431
343436
```

After testing, you'll probably want to replace `Echo !mitte!` with `(Echo 0F0900000A00143030303030303030303030303030303030!mitte!00)>COM3`, *(line `26`)*